# Pseudocódigo de arreglos

Tags: pseint, pseudocódigo

buenos días.

Estoy iniciando en la programación, mas especifico con pseudocódigo, intente llevar a cabo este ejercicio sin embargo, fue calificado como incorrecto.

Escribe un pseudocódigo para un programa que declare, recorra y manipule un arreglo. Este arreglo deberá contener los números del 1 al 8 y deberá imprimir el siguiente mensaje: El valor es par (en caso de que el valor sea par), de lo contrario, deberá mostrar el siguiente mensaje: El valor es impar (y después de recorrerlo, agregarás el número 9 al arreglo).

Mi respuesta fue:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las observaciones de mi instructor son:

- La comprobación de par e impar debe ser en los elementos del arreglo, no en el indice o iterador del ciclo
- Al final solo se debe asignar el valor nueve al fin del arreglo.

Me apoyan, por favor, cómo es la respuesta correcta.

Gracias de antemano, saludos.

Comment: No entiendo porque preguntas a nosotros en lugar de a tu profesor el porque de los errores que te marca. Sin embargo, estaria bien que digas que entendiste de la correccion, y porque piensas que esta bien, para directamente no decirte que esta mal, si no que aprendas a entender que hiciste mal... y ya te lo puse en la otra pregunta, no uses imagenes, tu codigo debe ir como texto

Comment: **¿cómo es la respuesta correcta?** Eso va a depender de lo que tu profesor considere *correcto*. Por otro lado tu código recorre 2 veces el arreglo, de eso no hay necesidad. Debes recorrer tu arreglo completo mostrando si el elemento es par o impar, cuando termines de recorrerlo agregas el 9, es lo que dice tu profesor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que deberia ser algo asi:

```
  Definir num como entero
  Dimension num[9]
  num[0]=0
  num[1]=1
  num[2]=2
  num[3]=3
  num[4]=4
  ...
  num[7]=8
  
  Para i<-0 Hasta 7 Con Paso 1 Hacer
     Si num[i]%2=0
      Escribir "el valor es par"
     SiNo
      Escrbir "el valor es impar"
  Fin Para

  num[8] = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Configurar PSeInt para que acepte dimensionar dimensiones con variables.

```
 Proceso sin_titulo
    Definir n Como Entero;
    n<-10;
    Dimension arreglo(n);
    Definir arreglo, i Como Enteros;
    Para i <- 0 Hasta n-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        arreglo(i)<-i; 
        Escribir arreglo(i); 
        Si arreglo(i) % 2 = 0 Entonces //Si el elemento de la posición i del arreglo es par
            Escribir "El valor par";
        Sino
            Escribir "El valor impar";
        FinSi
    FinPara
    arreglo(8)<-9; 
FinProceso
```